# Android Maps API V2 Shows only Grid, no map in debug. Normal?

Tags: android, grid, maps

I'm on an Android project that will use Google Maps.

After registering myself in the Google API Console and Activated (correctly I think) the Google API V2 service, I try to launch a simple Activity that contain a MapView.

But I have one problem : When I launch my application, the map doesn't appears. Here is the steps I followed :

1.) Keep the SHA1 keycode from my debug.keystore by using the command

```
keytool.exe -list -keystore C:\Users\beef\\.android\debug.keystore
```

2.) I entered that key in my API console, with the SHA1 Code.

3.) I activated the following services in my API Console : "Google Maps Android API v2" and "Google Maps API v2"

4.) I entered in my AndroidManifest.xml and in my layout.xml (which contains the MapView) my key.

5.) I wrote some code.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testmap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-feature
   android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView=null;
private MapController mapController=null;
private GeoPoint geoPoint=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    GeoPoint gPoint = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);
    mapController.setCenter(gPoint);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

And my layout.xml :

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="<MyAPIKey>"/>
```

I've read on StackOverFlow's posts that it's normal to have no map displayed (only the grid). But I would like to have a definitive answer.

I've also tried to export as signed application and install it on my Android phone, and I've the same result.

Maybe it can help you, I've got one error in my logcat when I'm on my application :

```
01-17 12:27:41.394: W/System.err(801): IOException processing: 26
01-17 12:27:41.404: W/System.err(801): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
01-17 12:27:41.404: W/System.err(801): at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
```

If anyone can help me,

Thanks,

Beef

Comment: Yes its normal to not get map( image) get displayed, but they will start displaying if you sign app with production key and download via play.

Answer (score 0):

MapView is for API V1, you must use the new Fragment implementation for V2.

Read this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map

Comment: Next time, I suggest adding a little more detail, instead of just a link!