# Google maps not showing on mobile but are visible in emulator

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making an app that involves google maps..

The maps are working fine and map is pefectly visible in my emulator but when I install same app on my mobile the map only shows the grids...and no map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents, make sure Google play services is installed on the device which can be found here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

If that doesn't solve it more than likely you are using a debug key and not a production key.
It is normal for the maps to not show until the app has a production key and is downloaded from the play store.There was a similar question here:

[Android Maps API V2 Shows only Grid, no map in debug. Normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380486/android-maps-api-v2-shows-only-grid-no-map-in-debug-normal)

To get the production key refer to this guide:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Hope this helps. :)